# Enable matching of character sequence made up of regex control character

Tags: java, regular-expressions

Java `Pattern` provides flags that enables you match regex control characters. Passing `Pattern.LITERAL` or `16` as second argument will match any Unicode char, but not if you use a word bound with the Unicode regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("$", Pattern.LITERAL); //I could also escape \\$
Matcher m = p.matcher("$ $ $ $$");
int i = 0;
while(m.find()){
i++;
}
System.out.println(i + " $ were matched"); //---> 4 $ were matched

//Using word boundary will not match any $
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\b$\\b", Pattern.LITERAL); //
Matcher m1 = p.matcher("$ $ $ $$");
int i = 0;
while(m.find()){
i++;
}
System.out.println(i + " $ were matched"); //---> 0 $ were matched
```

As you can see, I want to match distinct $, But I am unable to do that.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/313970/matching-string-that-is-bounded-by-regex-literal#comment663488_313970

Comment: Using a regular expression to match substrings is the proverbial sledgehammer for cracking nuts.  Why not use String.indexOf() to find the characters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> As you can see, I want to match distinct $, But I am unable to do that.

Pretty simple answer: You are trying to match on word boundaries, but your string `"$ $ $ $$"` contains no \w (word-character) and thus no word boundary. So, no match.

Comment: How can the sequence of the dollar symbol be matched with boundary?

Comment: Never mind, From your description I now understand and know what to do. Thanks.